# Symfony Server crashes when extending FOSUserBundle's default template layout.html.twig

Tags: twig, fosuserbundle, symfony

I am trying to get the basic user login running from the FOSUserBundle.
I am using Symfony 3.0.6.

I followed the description to setup everything from the FOSUserBundle:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

DB is up and running everything seems fine except I cant figure out how to override the layout.html.twig from the FOSUserBundle.
I followed this description for achieving that:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html

I now have a file "layout.html.twig" in the folder "Resources/FOSUserBundle/views" with the content being the same as in the last link provided above.
This leads to the following error:

> Unable to find template "layout.html.twig" (looked into:
>   [somePathInfo]) in FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig at line 1.

Now I changed the first line in the "layout.html.twig" Template to be

```
{% extends 'FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

And this then leads to the symfony server to crash stating

```
>php bin/console server:run -v                                                                                                                       
 [OK] Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000                                                                           
 // Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
  RUN  "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "-S" "127.0.0.1:8000" "[PATH]\myProject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Resources\config\router_dev.php"
  RES  -1073741571 Command did not run successfully
 [ERROR] Built-in server terminated unexpectedly.
```

I am stuck here...
Any ideas are very welcome.

EDIT: The FOSUserBundle installed by the composer (which I use through the current PHP-Storm plugin) is installed at the path:

```
[projectPath]\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Resources\views\layout.html.twig
```

In the docu however allways "FOSUserBundle" only is mentioned and I don't know how to figure out if that mapping fits to the path in my project.
Any hints for this issue are very wellcome as well.

Comment: I hope you created layout.html.twig in app folder not inside your bundle forlder?

Comment: @DenisAlimov yes I did. Any ideas on how to figure out whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you override standart FOSUser layout you need to place your layout into `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig`. great, you did this. it's just a layout, it should not extend standart FOSUser layout, so remove line `{% extends 'FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig' %}`. But usually developers make one base layout, in my case it is `\app\Resources\views\base.html.twig`, so if I want to override fosuser layout I will have in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig` something like this

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}User Management{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

In first line you extend your base layout not FOSUser. You may not extend something, maybe you have separate complete layout for this template.

Comment: Thank you. You are right.
In the documentation it says "This example extends the layout template from the layout of your app...".
I misinterpreted this and thought it meant the "layout.html.twig" from the Bundle. However removing the extend line fixes it.
I have another question here: Can anyone tell how the mapping "FOSUserBundle" to the bundle stored under "/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/" happens? I don't find any mapping table or similar info that defines this mapping. How can I know which folder name to use when I want to add a Bundle folder to my "app/Resources" folder?

Comment: @user3440145 you should ask it in separate question with detailed information

Comment: yeah - i'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

The crash does make sense.

When you write:

```
{% extends 'FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
```

The Symfony will first try to load `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig`. Failing to find the file  will revert to similar path but inside the `vendor` directory. And if you are trying to extend FOS's template from within your FOS overriden template, that would create recursive loop:

```
app/Resource/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig 
^^ extends  
app/Resource/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig
^^ extends
app/Resource/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig
....
and so on...
```

So, this is not a way to solve the problem.

Make sure that your template is well placed in your `app` directory and not your bundle, as Denis Alimov suggested in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the answere (as well to @DenisAlimov).
The "layout.html.twig" resides at "../myProject/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig".

Your explanation makes sense. However I do provide "layout.html.twig" at the mentioned location.
So I would assume both my attempts should work.
Still none does.
Any hints on how to find the reason for this?

Comment: I edited my question regarding the installation path of the FOSUserBundle. Does this maybe include any information that helps?